# compare and sort header based on presence of equal match, python

Tags: python, sorting, header

Compare line in file 1 to line in files 2 and 3, if there's a match, list that value as first entry on the header. Is there a way to sort and order the file 1 so that its arranged in way

```
file1 entries
winter|mountain|snow
skate|slide
ice|water|freeze|melt


file2 entries
water
juice
mountain

file3 entries
sea
ocean
slide
climb


output file with sorted header
mountain|winter|snow
slide|skate
water|ice|freeze|melt
```

```
file1 = open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') 
file2 = open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') 
file3 = open('some_file_3.txt', 'r') 

FO = open('some_output_file.txt', 'w')


for line in file1:
    file1_list = line.split(|)
        for i in file1_list:
            for line2 in file2:
                if i == line2:
                    i.insert(0,line.pop(i.index(line2))) # how to sort order of header in file1?
            else: # look at file 3 for match entries between fil3\e1 and file3
                if i == line3:
                    i.insert(0,line.pop(i.index(line2))) 

    FO.write("%s\n" %(line1))
```

want output to look like this

```
output file with sorted header
mountain|winter|snow
slide|skate
water|ice|freeze|melt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a set of the words in the files 2/3, then sort the words based on their inclusion in the set:

```
S = set()
for name in ['some_file_2.txt', 'some_file_3.txt']:
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        S.update(f.read().split('\n'))

with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as f, open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write('|'.join(sorted(line.strip().split('|'), key=lambda x: x not in S))+'\n')
```

Output:

```
mountain|winter|snow
slide|skate
water|ice|freeze|melt
```

Content of `S`:

```
{'climb', 'juice', 'mountain', 'ocean', 'sea', 'slide', 'water'}
```

Comment: if there's a '>' character at the beginning of each line in file1, how can I retain it at the beginning of the line of the output file, and not have it move when/if it's sorted.  example  >mountain|winter|snow                                     >slide|skate            >water|ice|freeze|melt